# Problema columnas en PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

Estoy siguiendo un ejemplo para dividir la pantalla en 3 columnas, a mi proyecto agregué la librería de PrimeFaces 6.1, sin embargo no me funciona. Acá dejo el código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Guardar</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <div class="ui-g">
            <div style="background-color: green" class="ui-md-4">4</div>
            <div style="background-color: red" class="ui-md-4">4</div>
            <div style="background-color: black" class="md-g-4">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g">
            <div style="background-color: yellow" class="ui-g-4">4</div>
            <div style="background-color: blue" class="ui-g-8">8</div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres dividir la pantalla en 3 columnas y ya? Si es solo eso, yo usaría el elemento descrito en: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/full.xhtml

Comment: @ferpaxecosanxez buena, eso es exactamente lo que quiero hacer. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Pues te he entendido, para que te sea de más ayuda, te pongo el código en sí.

```
<!-- Lo sustituyes por tu body -->
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <!-- 3 partes verticales(Oeste, Centro y Este) -->           
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="33%">
                <p:outputLabel value="Mi parte Oeste" />
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" size="33%" styleClass="tu-clase-css">
                <p:outputLabel value="Mi parte Centro" />
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="33%">
                <p:outputLabel value="Mi parte Este" />
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucedes es que estas usando la etiqueta DIV para hacer de columnas. Ya que estas utilizando primefaces hay un elemento llamado **panelGrid** el cual te permite generar una tabla donde especfícas el numero de columnas que usaras:

```
<h3>Responsive</h3>
<p:panelGrid columns="3" layout="grid">            
    <h:outputText value="Content" /> 
    <h:outputText value="Content" /> 
    <h:outputText value="Content" /> 

    <h:outputText value="Content" /> 
    <h:outputText value="Content" /> 
    <h:outputText value="Content" /> 

    <h:outputText value="Content" /> 
    <h:outputText value="Content" /> 
    <h:outputText value="Content" /> 
</p:panelGrid>
```

Con todo te adjunto el enlace al [elemento](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml), y si gustas podrías revisar mas de ellos que te pueden ayudar en tu desarrollo. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar el componente.